# GCP VertexAI Feature Store error in ingest_from_df() on feature_time column

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, feature-store

I am trying to ingest a sample data into a feature store in GCP VertexAI but I am encountering an error in populating the `feature_time` parameter.

I am quite confused on what data type should I use in the `timestamp` column (loaded in `feature_time` parameter) in order to ingest the data to the Feature Store. I am doing the exact thing stated in the documentation as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.EntityType#google_cloud_aiplatform_EntityType_ingest_from_df)

This is the error: `InvalidArgument: 400 Source schema does not match the expected schema for this import. Type mismatches in source: Expected type and mode [TIMESTAMP, NULLABLE] for ts2, but got [DATETIME, NULLABLE].`

I am using `google-cloud-aiplatform==1.34.0`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Data with 2 columns: entity_id, flight_duration
df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')

feature_time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(sep=" ", timespec="milliseconds")
df['ts_column'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(feature_time_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

flights_entity_type.ingest_from_df(
    feature_ids=["flight_duration"],
    feature_time="ts_column",
    df_source=df,
    entity_id_field="entity_id",
)
```

Here are the `dtypes` of my dataframe

```
ts1                   datetime64[ns]
flight_duration       float64
entity_id             object
```

Any leads will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: which line gives you this error?

Comment: @gtomer it is this one `feature_time="ts_column"` in the `ingest_from_df()` function call